# Conditional Probability for mutually exclusive events - What is the probability $P(X_j = 1 \ \vert \ \text{Only one of } X_i=1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Suppose I have $n$ random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_n$ such that $X_i =\begin{cases} 1 & p_i \\[5pt] 0 & 1-p_i \end{cases}$.

I would like to find the probability that
$$P(X_j = 1 \ \vert \ \text{Only one of } X_i=1)$$

This is an abstraction of a likelihood function$^1$ I am trying to find, but you can also think of it a bit like winning a lottery with only one prize, but everyone has different chances of winning.

My source tells me it's $$\frac{p_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i} \tag{1}$$

but I can't quite understand how they arrived at this.

I feel like it should be more like $$\frac{\frac{p_j}{1-p_j}}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p_i}{1-p_i}} \tag{2}$$

however the result is quite a famous one (Cox's Partial Likelihood function) so I'm pretty sure the answer should be $(1)$.

Is there some interpretation of the fractions $\frac{p_{j}}{1-p_j}$? Are they some sort of rescaled probabilities?

The actual context uses conditional densities $f_{X_i \vert X_i \ge x} (x)$, not probabilities. Might that fix the matter?

1 [Cox regression, partial likelihood function](http://www.biecek.pl/statystykamedyczna/cox.pdf), Equation $(12)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p/1-p$ is called the odds ratio. Your intuition is correct, working with densities changes things a little bit. The “equivalent” of the odds ratio with a continuum of results is called the hazard rate, and Eq (12) of Cox’s paper is just (2) adapted to a continuum of states. That $\lambda$ is not a probability itself but rather the hazard rate, which is the derivative of the log of the probability function.

Comment: Thank you pedro!
I was thinking this too. Would you be willing to write the steps / working out to arrive at the expression in Eq (12)? I'm having trouble coming to that expression...Would really appreciate it.

As per me, the hazard rate version should be more like $\frac {{\frac {\lambda _{i}(t_j)}{S_i(t_j)} }}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {{\lambda _{k}(t_j)}}{S_k(t_j)} }$

Comment: Nevermind, you're right, I got it! The $\lambda_i$s in my previous comment should be $f(t_j)$ and then they become the hazard rate.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I was sleeping in my time zone haha. Glad it helped!